# Direct Sum of Vector Spaces proof

Tags: linear-algebra

I have read the the proof of the following theorem:
$U\oplus V \iff U+V $ and $U\cap V={0}$

 and failed to understand.
How can I prove that only ${0}$ is in the intersection? 
when direct sum is $w\in W=U\oplus V$ can be uniquely represented by $w=u+v$

Comment: What's your definition of the direct sum?

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane Sorry, added

Comment: If the intersection contains $x\ne0$ then $0=x+(-x)=0+0$ so the zero vector can be represented on two different way and then the sum isn't direct.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane $x\neq 0$ so both $x$ and $-x$ are in the intersection as it is a vector space?

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$$\underline{W=U\oplus V:}\;\;x\in U\cap V\implies\begin{cases}x=\overbrace{x}^{\in U}+\overbrace{0}^{\in V}\\{}\\x=\overbrace{0}^{\in U}+\overbrace{x}^{\in V}\end{cases}\implies \;\;x=0$$

$$\underline{W=U+V\;\wedge \;U\cap V=0:}\;\;u+v=u'+v'\implies u-u'=v'-v\in U\cap V\implies\ldots  $$